# SOAPUI picking up a JDBC request value to assert against soap response

Tags: jdbc, groovy, soapui

I have set up a test in SOAPUI where my first step is a JDBC query to db. This query returns 3 values. I have set all 3 values as properties in the JDBC step.

I then have another step for a Property Transfer and finally a SOAP request step.

I am passing two of my JDBC properties into the SOAP request step. This is all set up successfully. The final step I wish to do is to assert the final JDBC property against a specific value in the SOAP response.

I have this assert working so far but against a hard coded value ('9Jg') as per the groovy assertion below. I want to stop this value being hard coded and I want the value to be pulled from the JDBC property.

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContent )
def pxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)

def expectedCodes = ['9Jg'] 
def actualCodes = pxml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'CurrHospProductCode'}*.text() as List
assert expectedCodes.sort() == actualCodes.sort()
```

EDIT: based on OP's comment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Results>
   <ResultSet fetchSize="64">
      <Row rowNumber="1">
         <TW606_POLRELATION.HPOLICY>H00000032</TW606_POLRELATION.HPOLICY>
         <TW606_POLRELATION.CUSTOMER>26485588</TW606_POLRELATION.CUSTOMER>
         <TW304_PRODHIST.PRODUCT_1>FJ0</TW304_PRODHIST.PRODUCT_1>
      </Row>
   </ResultSet>
</Results>
```

EDIT: Picture of my test case is below.

[image]

EDIT: Including 3rd step response below. I am looking to assert the value in CurrExtrasProductCode

```
     <ns0:ServiceBody>
        <ns1:GetTreatmentTypesResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www./v1-0">
           <ns1:ProductAndTreatmentTypes>
              <ns2:ProductHistory xmlns:ns2="http://www./v1-0">
                 <ns2:CurrHospProductCode>9J0</ns2:CurrHospProductCode>
                 <ns2:CurrHospProductDesc>Saver $500 excess</ns2:CurrHospProductDesc>
                 <ns2:CurrHospProductStartDate>2016-06-14</ns2:CurrHospProductStartDate>
                 <ns2:CurrHospProductExcessPaid>No</ns2:CurrHospProductExcessPaid>
                 <ns2:PrevHospProducts/>
                 <ns2:CurrExtrasProductCode>08S</ns2:CurrExtrasProductCode>
                 <ns2:CurrExtrasProductDesc>Saver Flexi Extras</ns2:CurrExtrasProductDesc>
                 <ns2:CurrExtrasProductStartDate>2016-06-14</ns2:CurrExtrasProductStartDate>
                 <ns2:CurrExtrasProductlengContCover>15</ns2:CurrExtrasProductlengContCover>
                 <ns2:PrevExtrasProducts/>
                 <ns2:PolicyStartDate>2016-06-14</ns2:PolicyStartDate>
                 <ns2:CurrAddOnProducts/>
              </ns2:ProductHistory>
```

Comment: So you want the third JDBC value as the expected value ?

Comment: Thats right. Instead of my assert stating def 'expectedCodes = ['9Jg']' id like my assert to look for the remaining value from my JDBC step.

Comment: Would you mind providing sample response?

Comment: Sure. Assuming you mean response from the JDBC call. <br/>  
    <Results>
    <ResultSet fetchSize="64">
        <Row rowNumber="1">
            <TW606_POLRELATION.HPOLICY>H00000032</TW606_POLRELATION.HPOLICY>
            <TW606_POLRELATION.CUSTOMER>26485588</TW606_POLRELATION.CUSTOMER>
            <TW304_PRODHIST.PRODUCT_1>FJ0</TW304_PRODHIST.PRODUCT_1>
        </Row>
    </ResultSet>
</Results>

Comment: Sorry. Struggling with formatting as code in comments.

Comment: I have named 'TW304_PRODHIST.PRODUCT_1' as 'Product' as a property in the JDBC step

Comment: @Matt question is little unclear. can you please show the screen shot test case?

Comment: @Rao sure. Just updated original post with screen shot. Hope this is what you meant. I've not tried the answer below yet but will try later today hopefully.

Comment: @Matt thank for the update. Would you mind showing the 3rd step response as well which you want to assert?

Comment: @Rao No problem. Post updated to contain SOAP response example.

Comment: @Matt, thanks. Is it that jdbc response can have many rows and each product should be verified from 3rd step response?

Comment: @Rao The JDBC response contains 3 values in total. 2 of which are passed into the SOAP request. The remaining JDBC response value is then being used to assert against in the SOAP response against CurrExtrasProductCode. So the JDBC step contains my expected result while the SOAP response (step 3) contains my actual result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154747/discussion-between-rao-and-matt).

Comment: @Rao To answer your question above. The posted JDBC response above is the full response that I get. It has one row in it and three fields. I write the query to only return one row from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve your value from the resultSet in a groovy script or script assertion like this :

```
context.expand( '${NAME of JDBC Request#ResponseAsXml#//TW304_PRODHIST.PRODUCT_1}' )
```

(i'm not sure about the path, maybe you need to fill the full path to your value)

Comment: This worked. My code looked like this: `def expectedCodes = context.expand( '${JDBC Request for expected results#ResponseAsXml#//*:TW070_VALIDATION.CODE}' )`